# Removing Highlight Css in awesomplete plugin

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the plugin for awesomplete. What I am trying to do is remove the yellow highlight that pops up with the letters that you have already typed. For example http://jsfiddle.net/kohenkatz/fmgh29qo/2/ in the textbox start typing the word Java you will see the dropdown highlighting those letters. How can I remove that highlight?

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/fmgh29qo/10/

Start Typing "Ja" on the first option it is correct but it has a little yellow rectangle behind it that I am trying to have removed. Then on the second option it automatically turns the "ja" white when you hover over the second option. Will anyone please assist me with this?

```
/**
 * Simple, lightweight, usable local autocomplete library for modern browsers
 * Because there weren’t enough autocomplete scripts in the world? Because I’m completely insane and have NIH syndrome? Probably both. :P
 * @author Lea Verou http://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete
 * MIT license
 */

(function () {

var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

function $(expr, con) {
    if (!expr) return null;
    return typeof expr === "string"? (con || document).querySelector(expr) : expr;
}

function $$(expr, con) {
    return slice.call((con || document).querySelectorAll(expr));
}

$.create = function(tag, o) {
    var element = document.createElement(tag);

    for (var i in o) {
        var val = o[i];

        if (i == "inside") {
            $(val).appendChild(element);
        }
        else if (i == "around") {
            var ref = $(val);
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(element, ref);
            element.appendChild(ref);
        }
        else if (i in element) {
            element[i] = val;
        }
        else {
            element.setAttribute(i, val);
        }
    }

    return element;
};

$.bind = function(element, o) {
    if (element) {
        for (var event in o) {
            var callback = o[event];

            event.split(/\s+/).forEach(function (event) {
                element.addEventListener(event, callback);
            });
        }
    }
};

$.fire = function(target, type, properties) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");

    evt.initEvent(type, true, true );

    for (var j in properties) {
        evt[j] = properties[j];
    }

    target.dispatchEvent(evt);
};

var _ = self.Awesomplete = function (input, o) {
    var me = this;

    // Setup environment
    o = o || {};

    this.input = input;
    input.setAttribute("aria-autocomplete", "list");

    this.minChars = +input.getAttribute("data-minchars") || o.minChars || 2;
    this.maxItems = +input.getAttribute("data-maxitems") || o.maxItems || 10;

    if (input.hasAttribute("list")) {
        this.list = "#" + input.getAttribute("list");
        input.removeAttribute("list");
    }
    else {
        this.list = input.getAttribute("data-list") || o.list || [];
    }

    this.filter = o.filter || _.FILTER_CONTAINS;
    this.sort = o.sort || _.SORT_BYLENGTH;

    this.autoFirst = input.hasAttribute("data-autofirst") || o.autoFirst || false;

    this.item = o.item || function (text, input) {
        return $.create("li", {
            innerHTML: text.replace(RegExp(regEscape(input.trim()), "gi"), "<mark>$&</mark>"),
            "aria-selected": "false"
        }); 
    };

    this.index = -1;

    this.container = $.create("div", {
        className: "awesomplete",
        around: input
    });

    this.ul = $.create("ul", {
        hidden: "",
        inside: this.container
    });

    // Bind events

    $.bind(this.input, {
        "input": me.evaluate.bind(me),
        "focus": me.evaluate.bind(me),
        "blur": me.close.bind(me),
        "keydown": function(evt) {
            var c = evt.keyCode;

            if (c == 13 && me.index > -1) { // Enter
                evt.preventDefault();
                me.select();
            }
            else if (c == 27) { // Esc
                me.close();
            }
            else if (c == 38 || c == 40) { // Down/Up arrow
                evt.preventDefault();
                me[c == 38? "previous" : "next"]();
            }
        }
    });

    $.bind(this.input.form, {"submit": me.close.bind(me)});

    $.bind(this.ul, {"mousedown": function(evt) {
        var li = evt.target;

        if (li != this) {

            while (li && !/li/i.test(li.nodeName)) {
                li = li.parentNode;
            }

            if (li) {
                me.select(li);  
            }
        }
    }});
};

_.prototype = {
    set list(list) {
        if (Array.isArray(list)) {
            this._list = list;
        }
        else {
            if (typeof list == "string" && list.indexOf(",") > -1) {
                this._list = list.split(/\s*,\s*/);
            }
            else {
                list = $(list);

                if (list && list.children) {
                    this._list = slice.apply(list.children).map(function (el) {
                        return el.innerHTML.trim();
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    },

    close: function () {
        this.ul.setAttribute("hidden", "");
        this.index = -1;

        $.fire(this.input, "awesomplete-close");
    },

    open: function () {
        this.ul.removeAttribute("hidden");

        if (this.autoFirst && this.index == -1) {
            this.goto(0);
        }

        $.fire(this.input, "awesomplete-open");
    },

    next: function () {
        var count = this.ul.children.length;

        this.goto(this.index < count - 1? this.index + 1 : -1);
    },

    previous: function () {
        var count = this.ul.children.length;

        this.goto(this.index > -1? this.index - 1 : count - 1);
    },

    // Should not be used, highlights specific item without any checks!
    goto: function (i) {
        var lis = this.ul.children;

        if (this.index > -1) {
            lis[this.index].setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
        }

        this.index = i;

        if (i > -1 && lis.length > 0) {
            lis[i].setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");
        }
    },

    select: function (selected) {
        selected = selected || this.ul.children[this.index];

        if (selected) {
            var prevented;

            $.fire(this.input, "awesomplete-select", {
                text: selected.textContent,
                preventDefault: function () {
                    prevented = true;
                }
            });

            if (!prevented) {
                this.input.value = selected.textContent;
                this.close();
                $.fire(this.input, "awesomplete-selectcomplete");
            }
        }
    },

    evaluate: function() {
        var me = this;
        var value = this.input.value;

        if (value.length >= this.minChars && this._list.length > 0) {
            this.index = -1;
            // Populate list with options that match
            this.ul.innerHTML = "";

            this._list.filter(function(item) {
                return me.filter(item, value);
            })
            .sort(this.sort)
            .every(function(text, i) {
                me.ul.appendChild(me.item(text, value));

                return i < me.maxItems - 1;
            });

            this.open();
        }
        else {
            this.close();
        }
    }
};

_.FILTER_CONTAINS = function (text, input) {
    return RegExp(regEscape(input.trim()), "i").test(text);
};

_.FILTER_STARTSWITH = function (text, input) {
    return RegExp("^" + regEscape(input.trim()), "i").test(text);
};

_.SORT_BYLENGTH = function (a, b) {
    if (a.length != b.length) {
        return a.length - b.length;
    }

    return a < b? -1 : 1;
};

function regEscape(s) { return s.replace(/[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&"); }

function init() {
    $$("input.awesomplete").forEach(function (input) {
        new Awesomplete(input);
    });
}

// DOM already loaded?
if (document.readyState !== "loading") {
    init();
} else {
    // Wait for it
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
}

_.$ = $;
_.$$ = $$;

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're at now but I edited that second fiddle you put up

http://jsfiddle.net/w13wf0q1/

just changed those last two rules

```
div.awesomplete li:hover mark {

}

div.awesomplete li[aria-selected="true"] mark {
    background: hsl(205, 40%, 40%)!important;
    color: inherit;
}
```

If you want to remove anything to do with the highlighting altogether then in the script where it says

```
innerHTML: text.replace(RegExp(regEscape(input.trim()), "gi"), "<mark>$&</mark>"),
```

(line 97)

replace that with

```
innerHTML: text.replace(RegExp(regEscape(input.trim()), "gi"), "$&"),
```

That's stops the markup that's creating that from being generated in the first place.

based on that second fiddle again
http://jsfiddle.net/Lj1jms2w/

Comment: What about the section option when you hover over the second option it still shows a white box also?

Comment: trying to not show them what they already typed in on the choice "drop down"

Comment: if you hover over javascript when you have typed in ja you will see that little white box around the Ja that I want to get ride of as well

Comment: updated the answer to include what's probably more at the heart of what you're after - removing any of the highlighting of the text that matches what has been typed - in both boxes.

Comment: I was wondering if 1.) It is possible to lock the text box where it would force them to have a value that is listed in the data-list. and 2.) If it is possible to give a data-code for each value is the data-list so that when lets say "javascript" is chosen then a certain data-code also corresponds with that value... I was just curious if either of these are even possible

Comment: 1.) sounds unlikely, I have ideas around how it could be possible but honestly it's not standard text box behaviour so the user could find that confusing and/or annoying so probably best to not put too much effort into that.

Comment: 2.) that sounds like you want to initialise the list using the datalist/options or ul method mentioned on the awesomeplete website. That way you could give those tags an id, class or title or something to find as the value (via js). Sounds like you need to initialise using a select http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp but that's not an option by the look of it.

Answer (score 3):

You can change it by adding a style for the `<mark>` element, like:

```
mark{
    background-color:transparent !important;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmgh29qo/8/)

Comment: @KTE I'm not seeing that, but I updated the answer with padding and margin removed, and set the background to transparent instead of white...take a look at the fiddle again--updated that too.

Comment: Can you please assist me a little bit more?

Comment: Start Typing "Ja" on the first option it is correct but it has a little yellow rectangle behind it that I am trying to have removed. Then on the second option it automatically turns the "ja" white when you hover over the second option

Comment: Is there anyway you can help me fix these please?